# How is PGresult in postgreSQL a pointer?

Tags: sql, c, postgresql, pointers

I want to understand the syntax for function PGresult in the libpq - C Library for postgreSQL that **retuns a PGresult pointer**.

The syntax to create a variable pointer in C++ is `int *varPtr` and to create a function pointer is `int *(fcnPtr)()` where the variable pointed to by varPtr is an interger and fcnPtr is a function without parameters that return an integer, i.e., data type is declared ahead of the function pointer.

Function PGresult syntax is `PGresult *PQexec(PGconn *conn, const char *command)` so *PQExec would the function and PGresult the data type if  compared to the syntax to create a function pointer in C++.

Function `PGresult *PQexec(PGconn *conn, const char *command)` returns a **PGresult pointer**. Is **PGresult pointer** a C++ function pointer? After executing uery `PGresult *result = PQexec(conn, "SELECT datname FROM pg_database")`, result is a **PGresult pointer** pointing to the PQexec function or to a data array containing the result of the query?

Comment: `PQexec()` is a function that returns a `PGresult *`...

Comment: Thank you. PGresult * is a variable, a function, a pointer to a variable or a pointer to a function?

Comment: Er... none of the above. It's a type. You need to learn the basics of C before worrying about things like postgres.